# Converting CAD Annotation to geodatabase feature class using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, annotation, cad

Is there a way to list through DWG and pick out let's say only the annotations and feed them into a geoprocessing tool?

Similar to below in a feature class...

```
for ds in datasets:
    #Finds polyline feature classes and appends to sde
    for poly in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Polyl*",feature_dataset=ds):
        arcpy.Append_management(poly,  .....
```

I would like to pick out the annotations and feed them into the Import annotation tool. I can't seem to get it. The link below makes it look so easy but it doesn't work.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/cad/using-python-to-load-cad-data.htm

Comment: What do you get if you try for anno in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","Annotation",ds)? Have you tried arcpy.da.walk and describe the returned data to locate annotation feature classes?